# How to create dynamic UI in Asp.net web forms

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a table in dataabase with 10 columns and these 10 columns are input fields in web page. Now base on certain type of users who is accessing the web page I need to show only certain fields and I also need to change the order in which these fields are displayed in web page. I can show or hide input fields but I am not sure how to reorder input fields based on certain condition. Is it possible to do something using asp.net on server side or do i need to use jquery and  how can we acheive this?

Comment: Try with asp.net data control such as grid, and use bind with textbox and changes the order of strings As required in code behind

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing any of your code, if you even have any, then I would suggest something along these lines:

Have conditional logic for querying the data, based upon the type of user (read: role), like this:

```
switch (user.Role)
{
    case "Customer":
        // Call customer stored procedure to return data pertinent to Customers
        // Returns List<T>, DataSet, DataTable, etc.
        break;
    case "Admin":
        // Call admin stored procedure to return data pertinent to Admins
        // Returns List<T>, DataSet, DataTable, etc.
        break;
    case "SuperUser":
        // Call super-user stored procedure to return data pertinent to Super Users
        // Returns List<T>, DataSet, DataTable, etc.
        break;
}

// Apply the data structure (List<T>, DataSet, DataTable, etc.) to your display, like this:
GridView.DataSource = dataSource;
GridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: But all those columns dataentry fields in web page like textboxes checkboxes etc..... now i want to change the order of this input controls based on condition................